# xcode7: hit linker command failed with exit code 1 under

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode7-beta5

I hit below error when build app on real device(`ios9.0`) use `xcode7 beta`:

> ld: library not found for -lPods...... clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to

1. change the config "Enable Bitcode" to "NO".
2. hardcode Framework path under build setting tab

but it didn't help.

Comment: did u open workspace or Xcode project ?

Comment: @DheerajSingh yes, I opened Xcode project.I hit this error when I build and run my app on real device(iPhone 5).

Comment: If u are using pods there must be a workspace file into your project directory which is generated when u use pods.Try opening with it and then build the project.

Comment: @Dheeraj Singh yes ,use pods and open this project by double click xcworkspace file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check this framework if existed in your project folder,you can right
   click on this framework in Xcode.
2. if existed, delete this framework under Frameworks in Xcode and then copy this framework into Xcode again for re-reference.